# Efficient Semantic Text Similarity for Detecting Paraphrased Duplicates in a Large Text Collection

Tags: python, nlp, duplicates, text-mining

I'm facing a challenging task of efficiently finding duplicates in an extensive collection of text documents, even if they are paraphrased or slightly modified versions. This means that conventional string comparison methods may not be sufficient to detect such duplicates.

How can I implement an advanced approach that allows me to consider semantic similarities between the texts and obtain a robust solution? Are there any Python libraries or algorithms that are suitable for this highly complex problem?

Here's a simplified example to illustrate the problem:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def find_similar_texts(text, text_list, threshold=0.8):
    similar_texts = []
    for candidate_text in text_list:
        similarity_ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, text, candidate_text).ratio()
        if similarity_ratio >= threshold:
            similar_texts.append(candidate_text)
    return similar_texts

# Example texts
text1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
text2 = "A fast fox jumps over a lazy dog."
text3 = "A lazy dog is jumped over by a fox."

# List of texts
text_list = [text1, text2, text3]

# Calling the function with text1
similar_texts_to_text1 = find_similar_texts(text1, text_list)

print("Similar texts found for text1:")
for similar_text in similar_texts_to_text1:
    print(similar_text)
```

The above code uses the SequenceMatcher class from the Python library difflib to calculate the similarity between texts. The goal is to find texts that have a similarity ratio of at least 80% (adjustable with the threshold parameter).

Please share your expertise with me and guide me on how to solve this highly complex problem more efficiently and reliably. I'm open to any ideas and suggestions. Thank you in advance for your assistance!